# Over simplification of decimal to fraction converter jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here, in the following example, I've used `toFixed(1)` to keep only one decimal of the input. As a result, whatever the input is, I only get the values `x.0, x.1, x.2, x.3, x.4,` ... `x.9`. So the results are respectively `y 0/1, y 1/10, y 1/5, y 3/10, y 2/5,`...`y 9/10`. Here `x` and `y` are just any numbers.

But I'm trying to make it even more simplified such as:

```
1.0 -> 1
1.1 -> 1 1/5
1.2 -> 1 1/5
1.3 -> 1 2/5
1.4 -> 1 2/5
1.5 -> 1 1/2
1.6 -> 1 3/5
1.7 -> 1 4/5
1.8 -> 1 4/5
1.9 -> 2
```

What I'm trying to do here is to ignore fractions like `1/10, 3/10, 7/10, 9/10`.

This is the snippet that I'm working on:

```js
function Fraction() {}
Fraction.prototype.convert = function(x, improper) {
    improper = improper || false;
    var abs = Math.abs(x);
    this.sign = x / abs;
    x = abs;
    var stack = 0;
    this.whole = !improper ? Math.floor(x) : 0;
    var fractional = !improper ? x - this.whole : abs;

    function recurs(x) {
        stack++;
        var intgr = Math.floor(x);
        var dec = (x - intgr);
        if (dec < 0.0019 || stack > 20) return [intgr, 1];
        var num = recurs(1 / dec);
        return [intgr * num[0] + num[1], num[0]]
    }
    var t = recurs(fractional);
    this.numerator = t[0];
    this.denominator = t[1];
}

Fraction.prototype.toString = function() {
    var l = this.sign.toString().length;
    var sign = l === 2 ? '-' : '';
    var whole = this.whole !== 0 ? this.sign * this.whole + ' ' : sign;
    return whole + '<sup>' + this.numerator + '</sup>/<sub>' + this.denominator + '</sub>';

}

var text = $('#text').val();
var digit = (text * 1).toFixed(1);
var frac = new Fraction()
frac.convert(digit, false)
$('#result').html(frac.toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text" value="1.3456" />
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add a function to create your output as you want and use it in codes. Look at this

```js
function simpler(whole, x, y) {
  if (x == 0) {
    return whole;
  } else if (x == 1 && y == 10) {
    return whole + '<sup>' + 1 + '</sup>/<sub>' + 5 + '</sub>'
  } else if (x == 2 && y == 10) {
    return whole + '<sup>' + 1 + '</sup>/<sub>' + 5 + '</sub>'
  } else if (x == 3 && y == 10) {
    return whole + '<sup>' + 2 + '</sup>/<sub>' + 5 + '</sub>'
  } else if (x == 4 && y == 10) {
    return whole + '<sup>' + 2 + '</sup>/<sub>' + 5 + '</sub>'
  } else if (x == 5 && y == 10) {
    return whole + '<sup>' + 1 + '</sup>/<sub>' + 2 + '</sub>'
  } else if (x == 6 && y == 10) {
    return whole + '<sup>' + 3 + '</sup>/<sub>' + 5 + '</sub>'
  } else if (x == 7 && y == 10) {
    return whole + '<sup>' + 4 + '</sup>/<sub>' + 5 + '</sub>'
  } else if (x == 8 && y == 10) {
    return whole + '<sup>' + 4 + '</sup>/<sub>' + 5 + '</sub>'
  } else if (x == 9 && y == 10) {
    return Number(whole) + 1 + "";
  } else {
    return whole + '<sup>' + x + '</sup>/<sub>' + y + '</sub>';
  }
}

function Fraction() {}
Fraction.prototype.convert = function(x, improper) {
  improper = improper || false;
  var abs = Math.abs(x);
  this.sign = x / abs;
  x = abs;
  var stack = 0;
  this.whole = !improper ? Math.floor(x) : 0;
  var fractional = !improper ? x - this.whole : abs;

  function recurs(x) {
    stack++;
    var intgr = Math.floor(x);
    var dec = (x - intgr);
    if (dec < 0.0019 || stack > 20) return [intgr, 1];
    var num = recurs(1 / dec);
    return [intgr * num[0] + num[1], num[0]]
  }
  var t = recurs(fractional);
  this.numerator = t[0];
  this.denominator = t[1];
}

Fraction.prototype.toString = function() {
  var l = this.sign.toString().length;
  var sign = l === 2 ? '-' : '';
  var whole = this.whole !== 0 ? this.sign * this.whole + ' ' : sign;
  return simpler(whole, this.numerator, this.denominator);

}

function f() {
  var text = $('#text').val();
  var roundUp = 0.4;
  var digit = (text * 1).toFixed(1);
  var frac = new Fraction()
  frac.convert(digit, false)
  $('#result').html(frac.toString());
}

$('#text').on('change', function() {
  f();
});

f();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text" value="1.9" />
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But here, the fractions for `1.2, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.8` returns `error` and `1.9` doesn't return `2`. Any suggestion how should I fix it?

Comment: Wow!  It's really wonderful to see beautiful codes. Just the final issue of `1.9` is not returning `2` rather returning `1 1`.

Comment: This is absolutely fantastic. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Also an edit added. Check it. Your welcome, Good luck. ;)